# HTTP "redirect" with node.js - Is there a module?

Tags: node.js, rest, http

not sure if I picked the right terminology, what I want to do is the following:

A node.js module receives http requests of all kinds (GET, PUT, POST ...). It should take these requests and route them to a different URL but keep all other input parameters as it received it.
The response coming in should then be handed back to the calling party.

I realized it with express and https modules for a simple GET and it worked. Before I start coding down the remaining stuff I was wondering if there is a module available for such a URL "redirect"?

Example:
http://server1/api/[parameters] + [body] => https://server2/api/[parameters] + [body]
and handing the response back.

Hope I was able to explain.

Comment: I ended up with node-http-proxy, but of course Lebowski's answer is matching, too!

Answer (score 1):

To redirect someone to another url you can use the code below:

```
response.writeHead(302, {
  'Location': 'your/404/path.html'
  //add other headers here...
});
response.end();
```

with this response you must also include the appropriate status code for redirection(301, 303) according to your situation.
You can see full list of status codes here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think I didn't choose the correct word. I don't want this redirect to be transparent to the end-user/ calling party. more like a proxy server which handles the incoming request and forwards it to a different address, then maps it back to the caller (a black box so to say).